# Inserting output in a variable

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, zabbix, netstat

I need to install Zabbix agent in some servers, about a thousand. In each server (Windows 2008 and 2012) I'd like to check if port 10050 is used, and if it is, then I need to know who is using it which process, and if it's Zabbix I stop it. Like this:

```
$id = Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalAddress 0.0.0.0 -LocalPort 10050 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty OwningProcess;
if (-not $id ) {
    Write-Host "$zabbix Port Opened"
    if (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "Name='Zabbix Agent'") {
        Write-host "Already exists. Deleting..."
        $servZabbix = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "Name='Zabbix Agent'")
        $servZabbix.Delete()
```

My challenge is on Windows 2008 servers that are using PowerShell v2 (I guess).
I wanted to do a universal PowerShell script that works in any version of Windows Server.
Can you guys help me with it?

Comment: Which part of this is not compatible with Powershell v2?

Comment: You can execute "Invoke-Command  -Computername <server> -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.psversion}" to get the Powershell version.

Comment: @MaximeFranchot `Get-NetTCPConnection` isn't POSH2. You can open powershell in version 2.0 mode: `powershell.exe -Version 2.0` and do testing if you want ...

Comment: @VertigoRay Thanks, I was genuinely asking if you thought I was trying to be condescending :) I guess I meant more for the question asker to make it clear in their question.

Comment: @MaximeFranchot:  Get-NetTCPConnection isn't available yet on PowerShell v2 on Windows Server 2008. Replying your second comment..it's the another way, I could open my v2 in v4 version but it's not possible and an update is not an option.

Comment: @JeroenHeier: I need to work independently of PS version. It must be "universal".

Answer (score 0):

I would go a different route with this:

1. Use `Get-Service` to see if Zabbix is a service.
2. If so, use `(Get-WmiObject 'Win32_Product' -Filter 'Name LIKE "Zabbix%"').InstallLocation` to get install information back on Zabbix.
3. Use `Get-Content 'agent.conf' | ?{ $_ -like 'ListenPort=*' }` to check Zabbix's config for the port it's configured to use; else default port is being used.

If WMI doesn't have the `InstallLocation` the registry definitely should.

Not behind a server with Zabbix right now, but thought this would help point you in a working direction. I'll check on you in the morning when I'm at the office and can do some real testing with my Zabbix Agents.

Comment: I agree with you but, first, I need to know if there is something listening on port 10050 and if it is Zabbix. If isn't I do nothing. But if it is Zabbix I stop it, exlclude de service and then I reinstall Zabbix in a differente location. But I'm goig to use some part of your idea to think different and try something else. Thank you for a while.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the process listenging on a particular port in a way that is compatible across PowerShell versions you can parse the output of the [`netstat`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961504.aspx) command:

```
& netstat -ano | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '(TCP|UDP)\s+(\S+):(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S*)\s+(\d+)$'
} | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Address = [ipaddress]$matches[2]
        Port    = [int]$matches[3]
        PID     = [int]$matches[6]
    }
}
```

Then you can filter the objects by port and use [`Get-Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) to determine the name of the process associated with it:

```
... | Where-Object {
    $_.Port -eq 10050
} | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Process -Id $_.PID
} | Where-Object {
    $_.ProcessName -eq '<name of Zabbix agent process>'
}
```